# Are there places you can't go in the US without paying tolls?

Tags: driving

I work a job that requires 100% travel. I cannot recall ever having to pay a toll since I use Google maps with the "avoid toll" feature. Yet, I have work mates who regularly claim that they go to jobs which absolutely require tolls. Is that possible in the US? I did [a little digging](https://www.google.com/search?q=places%20you%20can%27t%20go%20without%20paying%20tolls&oq=places%20you%20can%27t%20go%20without%20paying%20tolls&aqs=chrome..69i57.12534j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=places%20you%20can%27t%20go%20without%20paying%20tolls&start=10) on Google and couldn't find anything.

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: You'd have a hard time in the SF Bay area if you wanted to travel between San Francisco and Oakland without tolls. The 10 mile route that goes over the toll bridge becomes a 70 - 80 mile roundabout route if you want to avoid the toll bridges. So technically you can escape the toll, but it's not very practical. Avoiding the tolls for the 8 mile Sausalito -> San Francisco trip means a 120 mile trip around the bay.

Comment: Right Johnny, but that's my point. There is a round about way to do it. Impractical, yes. But when your corporation is punishing you for doing tolls and thus incentivises the windshield time, it becomes practical. Yet I've never actually had a case where it was not possible to do a round about way, which is the claim I'm skeptical of.

Comment: if you can rephrase this to be more touristy then travel.SE would be a place you can get an answer

Comment: And further, does it have to be by road? That same SFO-Oakland trip could be made by boat or aircraft, probably by train, bicycle, even on foot.

Comment: Yes, it has to be by car.

Comment: When I tell Google to avoid tolls it still routes me through a toll going to Boca Grande, Florida.  Looking at the map I see no other roads beyond the toll bridge.  (This was simply the first success on looking for islands with toll bridges, I see no reason to think there aren't more.)